# Continuous Functor on Vector Spaces induces Functor on Vector Bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-spaces, category-theory, vector-bundles

Let $T$ be a *continuous* functor between two different categories of  finite dimensional vector spaces, $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$.

Then we would like to define a functor between categories of vector bundles whose typical fibers lie in $\mathcal{C}$ or respectively in $\mathcal{D}$.

In Atiyah's *K-Theory* 1964 book, he defines the functor $T$ acting on a vector bundle $p:E\to X$, as a set, to be the *union* of the fibers $$ T(E):=\bigcup_{x\in X} T(p^{-1}(\{x\}) $$

and then goes on to define a topology on $T(E)$ which indeed makes it a vector bundle.

In other sources (e.g. Milnor & Stasheff), $T(E)$ is defined rather as the *disjoint union*: $$ T(E):=\coprod_{x\in X} T(p^{-1}(\{x\}) $$ though they then follow a similar construction for the topology of $T(E)$.

**My question is**: Is there a way to use [the natural topology that comes from the disjoint union construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)), and thus only define $T(E)$ as the above disjoint union with its natural topology?

For me the topology of each $T(p^{-1}(\{x\})$ is not so clear, because $T$ is a functor of vector categories and not of $Top$, so any topology that $p^{-1}(\{x\}$ has as a subspace of $E$ is "lost" when applying $T$ on it.

If the answer is "no", is there a somewhat more natural or "universal" way to define $T$ acting on the category of vector bundles?

Comment: Obviously, you cannot use the disjoint union topology. That will fail to give a vector bundle.

Comment: The union has to be disjoint. Otherwise you won't get a natural projection map to $X$.

Comment: @archipelago, tell that to Atiyah (pp. 6 of K-Theory).

Comment: PPR: @archipelago is right. The "$\bigcup$" sign was either a typing error, a printing error, or abuse of notation.